# Android No Running Emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, jetbrains-ide

[image]

DeviceManager says that Nexus 6P is Online, but there is no running emulator

Cannot click launch beacuse launch button is disabled.

After restart Android studio, nothing change.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and solved it by restarting the computer finally~